# Jenkins pipeline parallel not exeucting

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to test out the parallel functionality for a Jenkins pipeline job, but for some reason the individual build steps of the parallel job never get passed off to an executor and processed. Normal single-threaded pipeline jobs have no issue processing. I tried restarting the Jenkins server in case some resources were locked up, but it did not help.

The full script I'm trying to execute is:

```
def branches = [:]
branches["setup"] =  {node("nsetup") {
        echo "hello world"
    }}
    parallel branches
```

I have only one node, the master, and it has 5 available executors. It is configured to "use as often as possible". I'm pretty new to Jenkins and setting up a server for the first time, so maybe there's something I missed in the configuration that isn't related to the job.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And 2 minutes after I post I figure it out! Every time.

Turns out I just didn't have any idea how the "node" command really works. By specifying a parameter in the parentheses, it was preventing it from releasing to an executor. I'm guessing that must tell it to try executing on a certain node matched by label, and I was using it like it was some random logging field. Oops!

Comment: Please show your working code so that others might learn from it.

Comment: Sorry, it's been years and I don't have Jenkins or remember the code. But I can mark it as closed!